# Android Database Example by a JavaGeek

Tags: android, sqlite

Has anyone out there used this rather tidy database example (for beginners like me) by Chryssa Aliferi..? The entire code for the example is at the link below, so I won't reproduce it here;

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/database/android-database-example/

I think it was setup for Eclipse, however I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2 and I get "error: cannot find symbol method" on two occurrences of getTitle() and one of getId() in MainActivity. Why can't the methods, which are present in Book.java part of the app, be resolved...?

I did get the app to run ok, after I hacked it a bit by dropping off .getTitle() and hard-coded the getId() to 1. Now I can only edit one record and I get the full string returned by the getAllBooks function...

Book [id-1, title=The Great Gadsby, author=F. Scott Fitzgerald]

This issue is exactly the same as asked by Michael Davis Feb 7 at 20:45

Comment: Please check out SO's "how to ask" section - you'll have more luck getting an answer if you post a simplified, reproducible copy of your problem in the question itself rather than just linking to an external site. Moreover, that external site could go down and then the question can no longer be answered.

Comment: Yes thanks, appreciate that. Bit of a long shot really, just hoping someone else might have come across the same problem with that particular example. Someone had, but no solution there either.